# WebAPI HTTPDelete method not found via request but found in Swagger

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I have `API controller` with method:

```
    [Route("campaigns")]
    [HttpDelete]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Delete(string brandId,string campaignId)
    {
        try
        {
            var merchantId = CurrentUserInfo.GetMerchantId();
            await _service.DeleteAsync(merchantId, brandId, campaignId);
            return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log(e);
            return BadRequest(e.Message);
        }
    }
```

And from `angularJS` `app` I sending request:

```
 $http.delete(config.resourceNames.campaign, { params: { brandId: brandId, campaignId: campaignId } })
            .then(function (response) {
                return response;
            }, function (error) {
                return error;
            });
```

Config file:

```
 var resourceNames = {
    campaign: '/api/campaigns'
};
```

So the routing is valid.
But the request always return `404 NOT FOUND`.

I checked it via `Swagger` and that `DELETE` method is visible at the list but when I try to use it. It also return `NOT FOUND`.

Why this happing?

**Edit:**

While using "ISS Express" there is error 404 but when I switch to "Local ISS" the error change to 405 Method not allowed.

Comment: Use fiddler to see what's the actual request look like, maybe you will find your error there.

Answer (score 0):

May be you need to write:

```
[Route("api/campaigns")]
```

Comment: controller have "api" prefix.

Comment: It seems something wrong with routing as it shows `404 NOT FOUND` error which means unable to hit target action. Are you sure `config.resourceNames.campaign` reflects the correct route?

Answer (score 0):

I have run into this a couple of times. While I am not certain what the underlying cause is, I can say that naming routes has helped tremendously. Try this:

```
[Route("campaigns", Name = "delete-campaign")]
```